# Why does this condition always return false?

Tags: java, if-statement

Could anyone please tell me what is wrong with the following code. It doesn't show any result.

The integer a,b,c are the side of an right angle triangle.(was solving Project Euler problem 39)

If I use || in place of && , it shows the desired result based on the || condition. But doesn't work with the && condition

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    int a,b,c;
    for (a=1;a<120;a++){
        for(b=120;b>0;b--){
            c= 120-(a+b);
            if (((c) > (a+b)) && ((c*c)==(a*a)+(b*b))){
                    System.out.println(a + " , " + b +" , " + c);
                    System.out.println("**************");

                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"Works with `||` but not with `&&`"* has absolutely no functional meaning. If you have no output, it simply means that there's no iteration that evaluates `(c) > (a+b)` AND `(c*c)==(a*a)+(b*b)` BOTH to `true` *at the same time*.

Comment: I think you just meant the right-hand-side condition to test for `c<a+b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply, it's because this expression:

```
((c) > (a+b))
```

...never returns true in your example for any *valid* right angled triangles, and since the && condition requires both operands to evaluate to true, the if statement isn't executed.

You can see this quite clearly if you put in the following lines:

```
System.out.println("C: " + c);
System.out.println("A+B: " + a+b);
```

Comment: .. Or mathematically, a side of a triangle can not be greater than the sum of other two sides.

Comment: The condition here is not giving you true return as because its not satisfying the condition

Comment: Thanks berry120, how could I possibly forget the first rule of a triangle.. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

second part of && condition will always be false if first it true. if c > (a+b) then c*c > (a+b)*(a+b) => c^2 > a^2 + b^2 + 2ab then c^2 != a^2 + b^2

Answer (score 0):

Isn't a+b always 121? making c always -1, making c > a+b an illogical comparison? Just what are you attempting to do here?

Anyway, add some System.outs after each { so you know what is happening.
Also add System.out.println( c + " " + a + " " + b + " " + (a+b) + " " + (c*c) + " " + ((a*a)+(b*b))); to see all the parameters in your comparison to make sure you get what you expect before the **if** itself.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically both this conditions will never be true that is why && results into false and || works as one of the condition is true in a situation.

```
(c > (a+b)) && (c*c==(a*a)+(b*b))
```

If a number is greater than sum of two number then square of the number will be also greater then sum of square of two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        int a,b,c;
        for (a=1;a<120;a++)     {     
            for(b=120;b>0;b--){
                c= 120-(a+b);
                System.out.println(c+">"+(a+b)+" && "+(c*c)+" == "+((a*a)+(b*b)));
                if (((c) > (a+b)) && ((c*c)==(a*a)+(b*b))){
                        System.out.println(a + " , " + b +" , " + c);
                        System.out.println("**************");

                    }
                }        
            }
        }
```

and check yourself

i.e.

```
-66>186 && 4356 == 17330
-65>185 && 4225 == 17137
-64>184 && 4096 == 16946
-63>183 && 3969 == 16757
-62>182 && 3844 == 16570
-61>181 && 3721 == 16385
-60>180 && 3600 == 16202
-59>179 && 3481 == 16021
-58>178 && 3364 == 15842
```

...